# Need my SQL Query translated to Entity Framework code query

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I need to able to translate my sql query to EF code, my sql query is using one where statement of IN operator and not sure how to also do that in EF.

I have tried doing a EF code the follwing code below but is not working.

```
 private ManufacturingDbContext _manufacturingDbContext;

    public List<string> GetManufacturerOrders()
    {
        var context = _manufacturingDbContext;
        var ids = new[] {1, 2};

        var manufacturingOrderList = context.ManufacturingOrders.Where(s => s.statusId == ids.Contains(s.statusId)).Select(o => o.lookupCode).ToList();

        return manufacturingOrderList;
    }
```

Here is the sql query where I need it translated to EF Code

```
        select      
        o.lookupCode 

        from        dbo.ManufacturingOrders o
        where       o.statusId in(1, 2)
```

the end result of this is to just get the lookupcode as you can see in my sql query, and that will display in my app. I looked other sites in google and also here and I could not find an exact answer of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
  var manufacturingOrderList = context.ManufacturingOrders
                                      .Where(s => ids.Contains(s.statusId))
                                      .Select(o => o.lookupCode)
                                      .ToList();
```